# Windows Fullscreen API, browser behaviour

Tags: windows, firefox, fullscreen

This turned out to be a more difficult thing to achieve than I expected.

Using Windows 10, I want to be able to resize fullscreened browser windows. F11 enables fullscreen mode, in the past I could use window managers to manipulate fullscreen browser windows to resize them, achieving what's basically a fullscreen windowed mode: no title bar or window borders, navigation bars fading in and out on hover. This is still possible with explorer windows, but not browsers.

How would I go about getting a fullscreen browser window to behave like an explorer window, responding to calls from a window manager? Can I somehow trick the browser into thinking my screen resolution is something smaller than its actual display resolution?

Comment: Do you just want to resize Firefox to the whole screen, or only to get rid of visual components such as the address bar?

Comment: I want to resize fullscreen Firefox to not fill the whole screen. So fullscreen functionality (no bars, no borders) in a non-fullscreen window.

Answer (score 0):

If the window (dare I say ANY window) is Full Screen, you cannot move it or resize it or make it look like a non Full Screen window.

Not possible.

Windows 7, 8, 10 and 11.

Just use a resizeable Window that is "almost" full screen.

That will work.

**Note:**  I just saw in Edge that if you have it Full Screen, and then attempt to move it, Edge switches out of Full Screen. Same with Windows Explorer. This is in Windows 11 and Windows 10. This may be what you are seeing. But to be clear, moving the window shifts out of full screen. iTunes, for example cannot do this. And if unchangeable Full Screen, you cannot move the window.

So true Full Screen (no automatic shifting out) will not allow moving.

Comment: This is not true. I used to be able to resize fullscreened browser windows and I am still able to resize fullscreened explorer windows now, using KDE Mover-Sizer. The same thing is possible with other window managers.

Comment: I have never seen any such thing in any modern Windows System.

Comment: https://s1.webmshare.com/gw5Wv.webm

Comment: I just saw in Edge that if you have it Full Screen, and then attempt to move it, Edge switches out of Full Screen. Same with Windows Explorer.  This is in Windows 11 and Windows 10. This may be what you are seeing. But to be clear, moving the window shifts out of full screen.  iTunes, for example cannot do this. And if unchangeable Full Screen, you cannot move the window.